# Не могу открыть файл

Tags: c#

Написал такую штуку, не работает. помогите! :)

```
void ОткрытьToolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;

    if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFileDialog.FileName); // проблема где-то тут
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Замените вашу строчку на мою

```
richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```